PyQt Ошибка SSL груз системы
При загрузке веб-страницы через движок PyQt6 я получаю в консоль множество ошибок: [14196:5292:0605/144729.706:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101.
Хотелось бы узнать у знающих людей, если я соберу программу в таком формате в exe файл и скрою консоль, а пользователь будет видеть графический интерфейс, ошибки будут по сути идти фоново - будет ли это как-то отражаться на производительности программы или нагрузке на процессор, систему компьютера.
Программа планируется для облегчения работы и лишние ресурсы есть, поэтому спрашиваю из любопытства, как это влияет на процесс - как чисто уведомления или более негативно?

то есть, в ас смущает не наличие ошибок, а то, что они выводятся в консоль?

я так понял, что бывает прописывают метод игнорирования выпадения ошибок SSL сертификата, но т. к. не хотелось бы переписывать код - интересен больше этот момент про вывод их...
